# Spectrometer design

Tags: design, optics

I am looking to design a compact spectrometer based on using one single concave grating as both the dispersive optic and the imaging optic. I am investigating these gratings:

https://www.edmundoptics.com/f/zeiss-concave-diffraction-gratings/39624/
I require a center wavelength of 1700nm (with min = 1680nm, max = 1720nm). Does anyone see a reason why using these UV wavelength optimised mirrors would not for for Infrared wavelengths? I have a design that assumes looking at the 2nd order but I do not know what diffraction efficiency I will get at these wavelengths.

Thanks,

Jordan.

Comment: This part of your question isn't understandable "...  would not for for Infrared wavelengths?" Your typo needs to be corrected.